# Looping through a PHP array in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, arrays

I've made an array that has all the file names in a certain directory. I've tested it and printed it to the screen. I want to use that array in javascript code, print it's members to the screen as well for a php for loop.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<body>

<?php
$i=0;
$files = scandir('uploads');
for($i=2; $i<count($files);$i++) {
    echo '<br>';
    print_r( $files[$i]);
}
?>

<script>
function func() {

    var id = prompt("<?php for($i=2; $i<count($files);$i++)echo $files[i];?>", "");

}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

This loops through the array $files and prints it to the screen, I want to loop through the same array in a window.prompt object in javascript, and print the list to the prompt popup.

Before the end of the body tag:

```
<script>
function func() {
    var id = prompt("<?php for($i=2; $i<count($files);$i++)echo $files[i];?>", "");

}
</script>
```

But this seems to not print any of the array to the prompt object.

However if I do:

```
var list = prompt("<?php echo $files[2];?>", "");
```

It actually prints an element of the array, without the loop. But I want to print all at once, how can I accomplish this?

I tried using `print_r()` for the php code in javascript but that doesn't seem to make a difference.

printing the array at a exact position like `$file[4]` works, but using a for loop doesn't.

Comment: you cant mix php and js like that. all the php is finished before any js starts. you could build a js array with the php, then loop that via js.

Comment: Why he couldn't, the php will do output to javascript on request, and the javascript will continue with static text

Comment: prompt will contain every file, then run, it wont be a js loop

Comment: There's no js loop, he did loop through php and echoed to javascript, and it became a static text later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `i` to `$i`, to be closer: `$files[i]` should be `$files[$i]`

```
var id = prompt("<?php for($i=2; $i<count($files);$i++)echo $files[i];?>", "");
```

use:

```
var id = prompt("<?php for($i=2; $i<count($files);$i++)echo $files[$i];?>", "");
```

Comment: Wow I feel like an idiot that I somehow missed that, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your code twisted to where PHP is in charge and Javascript is just the echo tool. PHP does all the loop control and Javascript takes the dynamic variable through a PHP insert.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <body>

 <?php
    $i=0;
    $files = scandir('uploads');
    for($i=2; $i<count($files);$i++) 
    {
     echo '<br>';
     print_r( $files[$i]);
     ?>
       <script type="text/javascript">
         prompt(<php? echo $files[i] ?>, "");
       </script>
    }
 ?>
```